# How to step-debug annotation processor during compile?

Tags: java, debugging, maven, ant, annotation-processing

I have an annotation processor for an annotation of retention policy=SOURCE.

I have not idea how to step-debug it.

- I have issued print statements, logger info when I run mvn install, compile or package or ant javac, and I see their sysouts in the compile log.
- However, I have no idea how to step-debug the processor in Eclipse. I mean, how do you step-debug compile-time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to invoke the Java compiler from Eclipse, using a debug configuration (you'll need to create the configuration manually, from the "Debug Configurations..." menu choice.

The "correct" way to invoke the Java compiler under JDK 1.6 or above is to use the [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) interface in [javax.tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html), which you get from the [ToolProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html) (I include all the links because there's a decent amount of class/package documentation that you should read).

The "quick-and-dirty" way (that *should* work, but I make no guarantees) is to invoke `com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main()`, passing it your normal command-line arguments. To do this, you'll need `tools.jar` on your classpath (it's found in `$JAVA_HOME/lib`).

Comment: hi, reading this answer as accepted, make me think it's a solution to the problem. By the way, , I do not understand what "invoke the Java compiler from Eclipse, using a debug configuration (you'll need to create the configuration manually, from the "Debug Configurations." means. can you explain better please? thanks

Comment: I added tools.jar and the processor jar to an existing project. Then used the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class as suggested. Created a Java application debug configuration with the tools.jar in the classpath, and javac arguments as the Program arguments. Worked like a charm - thanks!

Answer (score 7):

An option in recent times is to use something like http://github.com/google/compile-testing which lets you invoke the compilation job against arbitrary annotation processors, which you can set break points, step through, etc.

```
@Test public void testStuff() {
  // Create a source file to process, or load one from disk.
  JavaFileObject file = JavaFileObjects.fromSourceLines("test.Foo",
    "package test;",
    "",
    "import bar.*;",
    "",
    "@MyAnnotation(blah=false)",
    "interface TestInterface {",
    "  Bar someBar();",
    "}",

  // assert conditions following a compilation in the context of MyProcessor.
  assert_().about(javaSource()).that(file)
      .processedWith(new MyProcessor())
      .failsToCompile()
      .withErrorContaining("some error message").in(file).onLine(5);
}
```

This test expects you will get some error message because @MyAnnotation is incorrectly declared in the test data source.  If this assertion fails, you can run it in debug mode in your IDE, set breakpoints in MyProcessor, and step through with a full compiler environment active during debugging.

For unit testing specific methods *within* your processor, you can also use the @Rule called CompilationRule from which you can obtain Elements and Types utility classes in order to test specific logic in your compiler in a more isolated way.

Answer (score 2):

Annotation processing occurs during compilation, so normal debugging won't work. If you want to debug it in the context of you project, you can use Eclipse remote debugging, while having Gradle or Maven in debug mode. Then you can put breakpoints in the Annotation Processor's files.

See [Debugging an Annotation Processor in any project](https://blog.xmartlabs.com/2016/03/28/Debugging-an-Annotator-Processor-in-your-project/).

Disclaimer: I wrote the post.